# How to control ellipse colors in lattice xyplot?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I want to change `ellipse colors` and `width` within `lattice xyplot`.
Here is an example:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, groups=Species,
       data = iris, scales = "free",
       par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(pch = 18, cex = 0.9,col = c("green", "orange","brown"),superpose.line = list(lwd=2))),
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
           panel.ellipse(x, y, ...)
       },
       auto.key = list(x = .1, y = .8, corner = c(0, 0)))
```

I want to match ellipse colors with the points and increase their width.
[image]

Comment: `panel.ellipse(x, y, col = c("green", "orange","brown"), lwd=3,...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by `user20650` you can add additional options to the `panel.ellipse` function. In this case, you want to add the `col` and `lwd` options.

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra) # you forgot to mention this package in question

xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, groups = Species, data = iris,
       scales = "free", auto.key = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.8, corner = c(0, 0)),
       par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(pch = 18, cex = 0.9,
                           col = c("green", "orange","brown"),
                           superpose.line = list(lwd=2))),
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
           panel.ellipse(x, y, col = c("green", "orange", "brown"), 
                         lwd = c(5, 5, 5), ...)
       }
)
```

[image]